# line 1a on form 1040 es: for what time period should i be estimating taxes for?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Line 1a on IRS Form 1040ES says "Enter your expected income and profits subject to self-employment tax". My question is...  for what date range? Do I do "expected income for the quarter" or expected income for the year 2014, starting on Jan 1, 2014 and ending on Dec 31, 2014? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the "Self-Employment Tax and Deduction Worksheet".  Form 1040-ES itself doesn't have a line 1a.

Everything on this worksheet should be figures for the entire year.  At the very end  (line 17 on the "Estimated Tax Worksheet") you will divide by 4 to get your estimated tax payment for each quarter.